# windows Authentication in ASP.NET web api2 asks re login every time with Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have an angular application with .NET web api 2 as abackend. I want to enable Windows authentication. I have done everything and the following popup appears. However, I cannot proceed after this popup.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNS9O.png)

Here is the controller code that enables Windows authentication

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public Dictionary<string, string> WindowsLogin()
    {
        
        var name = User.Identity.Name;
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            result["User"] = name;
            result["Key"] = EncodePassword(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private String EncodePassword(String originalPassword)
    {
        SHA256 sha = new SHA256Managed();
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(originalPassword))).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFDqe.png)

Comment: Please don´t add code as image. Add it as formatted text to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please recommend a solution for this